# ASP.NET: Custom control that outputs multiple hyperlinks. How do I register the ClientIDs for AJAX (UpdatePanel)?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I have a custom control which is rendered as a hyperlink:

```
Public Class TestControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl
    Implements IPostBackEventHandler

    Public Sub RaisePostBackEvent(ByVal eventArgument As String) Implements System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent
        Trace.WriteLine("Hyperlink 1 clicked")
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        writer.WriteLine("<a href=""{0}"" id=""{1}"">Hyperlink 1</a>", _
                         Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Me, "Hyperlink 1"), _
                         Me.ClientID)
    End Sub
End Class
```

This works fine. It also works nicely when put inside an `UpdatePanel`: Only the UpdatePanel is refreshed, no full postback is performed.

Now I would like to output a second hyperlink in the `Render` method. If I use the same id (`Me.ClientID`), everything works nicely, but this obviously results in broken HTML (no two controls are allows to have the same `id` attribute). If I use different client IDs (like `Me.ClientID & "_1"` and `Me.ClientID & "_2"`), a full postback is performed when the hyperlinks are clicked.

Is there some way to tell ASP.NET AJAX: "*All postbacks of the following client IDs should be done asynchronously: ...*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a slightly different approach, which has been `UpdatePanel`-friendly in my experience, which you may want to consider.

Instead of generating HTML content directly in the `Render()` method, I inherit my control from `CompositeControl` and fill it with child controls in the `CreateChildControls()` method. With the controls collection populated, the render method sort of "takes care of itself."

To the Update Panel, this composite control is just a bucket of otherwise-ordinary server controls, so the built-in behavior "just works."

If you haven't worked much with composite controls, [here's a resource to get started](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/webforms/article.php/c12725). I tend to build the whole control tree rather than override the `RenderControl()` method, but it's a reasonable resource anyway.